# How to check if user has splitted Uber fare

Tags: ios, uber-api

Is there a way to check if fare was splitted between some users in Uber API? I'm not talking about UberPOOL where we can check that by "shared" property with riders in response from Ride Request.

Comment: No, there is not an API endpoint on if a user split a fare in the Uber app.

Comment: @KyleDavis So you mean that there's no way to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Uber's developer documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#limitations), the ride request api currently do not support **Splitting the fare** feature.